# Pass value from radio button to database

Tags: android, radio-button, radiobuttonlist

I made a layout which contains radio button. I want to pass value of selected radio button  to database so how can I get this value.?
  Code is given below..Please help me..

```
private View drawRadioTypeQuestion(Question question, ArrayList<QuestionOption> questionOptions) {
        LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(this);
        layout.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
        layout.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);

        TextView tv = new TextView(this);
        tv.setText(question.Question_Order + ". " + question.Question_Title);
        tv.setTextSize(16);
        // tv.setTypeface(PhoneStatus.getRobotoMediumTypeface(this));
        layout.addView(tv);

        RadioGroup rg = new RadioGroup(this);
        rg.setOrientation(RadioGroup.VERTICAL);
        for (QuestionOption opt : questionOptions) {
            RadioButton rb = new RadioButton(this);
            rb.setText(opt.Question_Answer_Value);
            rb.setTextSize(16);
            rg.addView(rb);
        }
        layout.addView(rg);

        PhoneStatus.overrideFonts(QuestionListActivity.this, layout);
        tv.setTypeface(PhoneStatus.getRobotoMediumTypeface(this));
        return layout;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this code

```
   rg.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            RadioButton rb = (RadioButton) findViewById(checkedId);
            String value = rb.getText().toString();
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Implement click listener on radio button. On onclick event add value of selected radio button to database..

Visit Here for official document

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/radiobutton.html

and

http://android-er.blogspot.in/2009/11/radiogroup-and-radiobutton.html

Comment: I am not using radio button from xml layout. I made radio buttons by java code..In that case how can I pass value of radio buttons to database.?